# Sql server COMMIT without Tran | Transaction?

Tags: sql-server-2005, transactions

According to msdn : the commit syntax is  :

[image]

However when I **omit** the `tran`/`transaction` words - it does compile and run with NO errors.[image]

How can it be working ?

Does it do something else instead ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The COMMIT in question is not actually COMMIT you think. See [COMMIT **WORK**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178628.aspx)

> COMMIT [ WORK ]
>   [ ; ]
>
> Remarks
>
> This statement functions identically to COMMIT TRANSACTION, except COMMIT TRANSACTION accepts a user-defined transaction name. This COMMIT syntax, with or without specifying the optional keyword WORK, is compatible with SQL-92.

So `COMMIT` by itself is `COMMIT WORK` which is identical to `COMMIT TRANSACTION`.
Ditto for [`ROLLBACK [ WORK ]`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174973.aspx)

After comment,

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION gbn
SELECT 1
COMMIT gbn -- fail
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION gbn
SELECT 2
COMMIT TRAN gbn -- works
GO
```

Comment: `except COMMIT TRANSACTION accepts a user-defined transaction name`.... but i didnt give him the name of the Transaction... thats the problem. + Im not talking about the `WORK` keyword. im talking about commit vs commit trans.

Comment: @Royi Namir: no, COMMIT by itself means COMMIT WORK. Nothing to do with a named transaction: if you did name it, you didn't mention that in your question. And with a name, you'd have to explicitly use `COMMIT TRANSACTION SomeName` or `COMMIT TRAN SomeName`. *Not* COMMIT by itself

Comment: So if i dont use any named transaction I can always use Commit alone. right ?

Answer (score 0):

`IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0` aims checking there is (at least) one pending transaction - if must be used with both `ROLLBACK` and `COMMIT` as executing these instructions without having any transaction open will generate an error